# How to use activemq wildcards for sending messages

Tags: activemq-classic

I try to send message to multiple queues according this documentation [ActiveMQ Wildcards](http://activemq.apache.org/wildcards.html). The idea is to send message to `PRICE.>` queue and receive them in queues `PRICE.STOCK.NASDAQ.ORCL` and `PRICE.STOCK.NYSE.IBM` (queues are created). But instead of forwarding messages to `PRICE.STOCK.NASDAQ.ORCL` and `PRICE.STOCK.NYSE.IBM` activemq create new queue `PRICE.>` that become this message.

I tried to send message with activemq admin tool (send mask) and spring boot application. Behavior is the same - message is placed in new created queue `PRICE.>`.Activemq was not additionally configured, I'm using configuration provided with activemq 5.15.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is only supported for subscribers, you need to send to a specific named destination when publishing a message.  You can use the [Virtual Destinations](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html) feature of ActiveMQ to define a target destination that forwards to some defined set.